# Django : Foreign Key column from formulary not working

Tags: python, django

I'm working with `Django 1.10.5` and I get an error that I am not finding a solution. All models seem to work correctly and all tables too except table `BirthCertificate` (see above).

I have a models file from my first app : **Identity models.py**

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Identity(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=12,choices=TITLE_CHOICES, verbose_name='Civilité')
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Nom de famille')
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Prénom(s)')
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=SEX_CHOICES, verbose_name='Sexe')
    birthday = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date de naissance')
    birthcity = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Ville de naissance')
    birthcountry = CountryField(blank_label='Sélectionner un pays', verbose_name='Pays de naissance')
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Nationalité')
    job = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Profession')
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Adresse')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Ville')
    zip = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Code Postal')
    country = CountryField(blank_label='Sélectionner un pays', verbose_name='Pays')
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Email', blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Téléphone', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.id, self.title, self.lastname, self.firstname, self.sex, self.birthday, self.birthcity, self.birthcountry,
                                                                    self.nationality, self.job, self.adress, self.city, self.zip, self.country, self.mail, self.phone)
```

Then I have another models from my second app : **BirthCertificate models.py** which takes two Foreign Keys from Identity models :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class BirthCertificate(models.Model):

    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Nom de famille')
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Prénom(s)')
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=SEX_CHOICES, verbose_name='Sexe')
    birthday = models.DateField(null=False, verbose_name='Date de naissance')
    birthhour = models.TimeField(null=True, verbose_name='Heure de naissance')
    birthcity = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Ville de naissance')
    birthcountry = CountryField(blank_label='Sélectionner un pays', verbose_name='Pays de naissance')
    fk_parent1 = models.ForeignKey(Identity, related_name='ID_Parent1', verbose_name='ID parent1', null=False)
    fk_parent2 = models.ForeignKey(Identity, related_name='ID_Parent2', verbose_name='ID parent2', null=False)
    folderId = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
```

Then, I have a form in BirthCertificate application that I'm filling. And I have a choice between some Identity ID in this form. But, when I'm filling and validate my form, I get this error :

```
Exception Value: (1048, "Column 'fk_parent1_id' cannot be null")
```

But, this column is not empty, because I selected a personn among the choice list :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j1oi.png)

I put my **BirthCertificate views.py** file too with the form function :

```
import requests, os, json, glob
from django.shortcuts import render, reverse, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from .models import BirthCertificate
from Identity.models import Identity
from .forms import BirthCertificateForm
from django.db import connection
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

@login_required
def BirthCertificate_Form(request) :
    # Fonction permettant de créer le formulaire Acte de Naissance et le remplissage

    if request.method == 'POST':

        Bform = BirthCertificateForm(request.POST or None)

        if Bform.is_valid() :   # Vérification sur la validité des données
            if '_preview2' in request.POST :
                post = Bform.save(commit=False)
                template_name = 'BC_preview.html'

            elif '_save2' in request.POST :
                post = Bform.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('BC_treated', kwargs={'id': post.id}))

    else:
        Bform = BirthCertificateForm()

    return render(request, 'BC_form.html', {"Bform" : Bform})
```

Do you have a solution ?
If you need some files or view, tell me because I spent 2 days without find any solution to my problem.

**EDIT FULL TRACEBACK**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/BirthCertificate/formulaire

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'BirthCertificate',
 'Identity',
 'bootstrapform',
 'Accueil',
 'captcha',
 'django_countries',
 'log',
 'Mairie']
Installed Middleware:
['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/valentinjungbluth/Desktop/Django/Etat_civil/BirthCertificate/views.py" in BirthCertificate_Form
  47.                 post = Bform.save()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  453.             self.instance.save()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  796.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  824.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  908.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  947.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1045.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1054.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  115.                 six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  110.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  205.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /BirthCertificate/formulaire
Exception Value: (1048, "Column 'fk_parent1_id' cannot be null")
```

Comment: Your view structure doesn't follow the typical pattern. Try restructuring it according to this example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-view .

Comment: @voodoo-burger Why my view doesn't follow the typical pattern ? I don't understand why my code is not structured from your point of view ^^

Comment: look at the link - for one thing you are not checking `if request.method == 'POST'`.

Comment: I edited it, but still the same error

Comment: I dont see anything in your current code that could be causing this. Maybe if you post the full traceback someone else can take a look.

Comment: Ok I will edit my question. I don't see any errors too and it's really strange because I didn't modify mi script. I just changed my MySQL database to an other distant server.

Comment: I found the solution ! In my Birthcertificate forms.py file, display fields didn't mention `fk_parent1` and `fk_parent2`. I don't know why these fields were not there ...